# How to make an Excel report using DataTable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, datatable

In my project I get data from the database and store it in a data. From datatable, I want to export data to Excel using FileExport DataTable, but the report of Excel result is the same as the data in data table.

I using this code for implement data table:

```
$('#grid').DataTable({
                ajax: {
                    url: '@Url.Action("Binding", "ETCPSummaryReport")',
                    data: {
                        SCode : spesial,
                        divisioncode: $("#Division").val(),

                    },
                },
                searching: false,
                destroy: true,
                bPaginate: true,
                bLengthChange: false,
                bFilter: false,
                bInfo: false,
                bSort: false,
                responsive: true,
                bServerSide: true,
                bProcessing: true,
                dom: 'Bfrtip',
                buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'excelHtml5',
                    title: 'Data export'
                }
                ],
                columns: [
                    { "title": "Name" },
                    { "title": "PAR" },
                    { "title": "Total" },
                    { "title": "TotalETCPPSR" },

                ],
                columnDefs: [
                    { visible: false, targets: 0 }
                ],
                order: [[0, 'asc']],
                displayLength: 25,
                drawCallback: function (settings) {
                    var api = this.api();
                    var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                    var last = null;

                    api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                        if (last !== group) {
                            $(rows).eq(i).before(
                                '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                            );

                            last = group;
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
```

but output in my report like this whereas I expect such a table:
[image: but output in my report like this]
[image: whereas I expect such a table]

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#grid').DataTable({
            ajax: {
                url: '@Url.Action("Binding", "ETCPSummaryReport")',
                data: {
                    SCode : spesial,
                    divisioncode: $("#Division").val(),

                },
            },
            searching: false,
            destroy: true,
            bPaginate: true,
            bLengthChange: false,
            bFilter: false,
            bInfo: false,
            bSort: false,
            responsive: true,
            bServerSide: true,
            bProcessing: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtip',
            buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'excelHtml5',
                title: 'Data export'
            },
            {
                extend: 'excel', 
                text: 'Download Excel'
            }
            ],
            columns: [
                { "title": "Name" },
                { "title": "PAR" },
                { "title": "Total" },
                { "title": "TotalETCPPSR" },

            ],
            columnDefs: [
                { visible: false, targets: 0 }
            ],
            order: [[0, 'asc']],
            displayLength: 25,
            drawCallback: function (settings) {
                var api = this.api();
                var rows = api.rows({ page: 'current' }).nodes();
                var last = null;

                api.column(0, { page: 'current' }).data().each(function (group, i) {
                    if (last !== group) {
                        $(rows).eq(i).before(
                            '<tr class="group"><td colspan="5">' + group + '</td></tr>'
                        );

                        last = group;
                    }
                });
            }
        });
```

Comment: I don't see any difference

Comment: {
                extend: 'excel', 
                text: 'Download Excel'
            }

add this code in "buttons"

Comment: https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/initialisation/export.html

visit this link and see demo now ..

Answer (score 0):

Excel can parse only a very limited set HTML and CSS. So some styles will not work at all.

First of all you have to ensure that your **CSS files** are included by **full qualified path and full qualified domain**. This is because when the browser passes the HTML file to Excel it is stored at a temporary location. But only *the HTML* file is stored at this location not all the included files. So a server relative link in this HTML file will point somewhere into the filesystem but not to your style sheet. Whether you get a warning from Excel or not depends on the Excel version and maybe user settings or group policies respectively.

Maybe this already fixes your problem. But don't expect the table to look exactly as in the browser. Colors will work, but Excel has sometimes fancy ideas of formatting values. It might be a hard work to get around all the pitfalls. You might need to use `mso-...` CSS styles to domesticate Excel.

Comment: yes but really, what I want is not about that but how can I make an excel report exactly like a table display on the web, I don't blame the CSS problem, I leave the report image I hope I don't have problems with CSS even though my report should be without color and style though click this link for see my image https://ibb.co/mWfriz